# Show that an field extension is algebraic (normal).

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $A/K$ be a field extension, I wanted to proof:

$A/K$ is normal iff for every irreducible polynomial $P \in K[x]$ which has a root in $A$, the field extension $A$ contains a splitting field for $P$.

Proof: If $A/K$ is normal, then every irreducible polynomial $P$ over $K$ which has a root in $A$ splits over $K$ in $A$, so $A$ must contain a splitting field (at least $A$ will do).

The other direction. That every polynomial which has a root splits is simple, because $A$ contains a splitting field. But how can I show that $A/K$ is algebraic?

Comment: I've only ever seen "normal" defined for *a priori* algebraic extensions. I just ran and checked Lang, see p. 237.

Comment: I think that algebraic **must** be a a given, otherwise we could say trascendent extensions may be normal...

Comment: It's from an exercise, so I think it's right... or can you give an example of an trancendent extension which contains a splitting field for every irred. polynomial which has a root in $A$?

Comment: Of course: the extension $\,\Bbb Q(\pi)/\Bbb Q\,$ , or any other purely transcendental extension, is a splitting field for every *irreducible* rational polynomial that has a root in it...

Comment: why that? the polynomial $(x-1)(x^2 + 1)$ has a root in $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)/\mathbb{Q}$, but does not split over this extension?

Comment: @Stefan, the polynomial $(x-1)(x^2+1)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is not *irreducible*. The only elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ that are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ are the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$. This is a consequence of $\pi$ being transcendental. I agree with the others that algebraic must be given. You got the point of the problem.

Comment: One more thing, when you say "(at least $A$ will do)." be careful; $A$ is not necessarily a splitting field for $P$. Remember that a splitting field has a minimality condition too.